# Fetch Title From UITableViewCell That is Being Deleted

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nsuserdefaults

I want to be able to fetch the title of the `UITableViewCell` that is being deleted with `commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle`. Here's my code that you need to know.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell : FavoritesTableViewCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Favorites Cell") as! FavoritesTableViewCell
        if(cell == nil)
        {
            cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("Favorites Cell", owner: self, options: nil)?[0] as! FavoritesTableViewCell;
        }

        cell.songTitle.text=favoriteSongs[indexPath.row].title

        return cell as FavoritesTableViewCell
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if editingStyle == .delete {

            // remove the item from the data model
            favoriteSongs.remove(at: indexPath.row)

            // delete the table view row
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
            let propertylistSongs = favoriteSongs.map{ $0.propertyListRepresentation }
            UserDefaults.standard.set(propertylistSongs, forKey: "favoriteSongs")


        } else if editingStyle == .insert {

        }
    }
```

The reason that I want to do this so that I can create a key for the UserDefaults. I was thinking this:

```
    var cell : FavoritesTableViewCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Favorites Cell") as! FavoritesTableViewCell
    UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "liked\(String(describing: cell.songTitle.text))")
```

But, I guess that didn't work, because the Key doesn't work whenever the `UserDefaults` bool is referenced. So, I need to fetch the songTitle.text from the `UITableViewCell` that is being deleted. Any ideas?

Comment: you just want current deleted song title or you want the all what goes already deleted ?

Comment: Since you have the indexpath to be deleted with you inside the method "commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle", you can get the title before you actually delete from the data source inside the

 if editingStyle == .delete { ... }

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is here

What I found from your code is first you are removing the object from the array but in place of deleting it you can get the title for that song from that index

Here is the detail with elaboration

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if editingStyle == .delete {

            print(favoriteSongs[indexPath.row]) //Here is your title for the deleted song

            // remove the item from the data model
            favoriteSongs.remove(at: indexPath.row)

            // delete the table view row
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)

        } else if editingStyle == .insert {

        }
    }
```

Comment: The only problem, is that I am using a struct, so `favoriteSongs[indexPath.row]` gets turned into `favoriteSongs[indexPath.row]`.title I get an error **Thread 1 EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_1386_INOP, subcode=0x0)**